# Get a list of all invalid XML tags using Regex?

Tags: java, xml, regex

I have XML contained in a string which has many invalid xml tags for an element, where a tag is "invalid" if it starts with a number. For example, the following are invalid:

```
 <1>....</1>, <123abc>, etc.
```

In XML, we'd identify certain tags as invalid:

```
 <tag1> ----> valid tag
     <1tagname>....</1tagname> --->invalid tagname
     <2tagname>....</2tagname> --->invalid tag name
 </tag1> ----> valid tag
```

I want to fetch a list of invalid xml tags and I want to add a special string as a prefix let's say "item" so as to convert invalid to valid tag name.

I am using Java language compatiable regex.

Comment: invalid tag mean which are not having closing tag ??

Comment: can you give an example ?

Comment: invalid tag name means that it should not start with number.

Comment: @abhijeet it will be having closing tag rght ?? or we can say it follow proper XML rule

Comment: I have provided an example. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
String result = yourstr.replaceAll("(?<=</?)(?=[0-9])", "item");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use stack.

**Explanation:**

it's like the finding if bracket expression is valid.
your code should work like this:

1. Read the xml
2. For every opening tag, push it into the stack
3. For every closing tag, compare it with the top of the stack
4. If they are not match - mark as problem - add prefix
5. If they match - pop out of stack
6. When finish reading the xml and there are element in the stack - add prefix and close the tags

This will solve the *simple* case.
There are some edge case, like have unmatched closing tag inside a legal tag and maybe more

Comment: Only problem with this is that no XML parser will successfully process ill-formed XML.

Comment: @MichaelKay - you don't need xml parser, you can run over the string, looking for open/close tag

Comment: OK, I read "read the XML" as "parse the input as XML". The point is that the input isn't XML, and the things we are looking for aren't (valid) tags; we're reading something approximating to XML, and looking for something approximating to open and close tags.